# How to return value from function without repeated function call or polluting global scope?

Tags: php, function

I have two functions, which are attached to hooks, and get executed at defined points or events in program life cycle. What is best approach, by function and design, when we want to pass some return values from one function call to another, but without repeated function call, or polluting global scope.

Here is, I hope well documented part of code:

```
/**
 * @array hookparams Hookparams array from both of function calls
 */
$hookparams = []; // initalized empty values

function hook_FunctionOne()
{
    //do something, than save result in hookparams array
    $hookparams['key'] = "Foo"; // return? But I can't call FunctionOne once more, and assign return value to temp variable
}

function hook_FunctionTwo(array $hookparams)
{
    //do something with returned hookparams array form function, than save result in hookparams array again 
    $hookparams['key'] .= "Bar"; // Result is "FooBar";
}

// Both functions are called here

run_hook("HookPoint1", "hook_FunctionOne");
run_hook("HookPoint2", "hook_FunctionTwo");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing parameter to a function by reference saved my day.Here is complete code:

```
/**
 * @array hookparams Hookparams array from both of function calls
 */
$hookparams = []; // initalized empty values

function hook_FunctionOne(&$hookparams)
{
    //do something, than save result in hookparams array
    return $hookparams['key'] = "Foo"; // return? But I can't call FunctionOne once more, and assign return value to temp variable
}

function hook_FunctionTwo(&$hookparams)
{
    //do something with returned hookparams array form function, than save result in hookparams array again 
    return $hookparams['key'] .= "Bar"; // Result is "FooBar";
}

// Both functions are called here

echo hook_FunctionOne($hookparams); // First function call

echo hook_FunctionTwo($hookparams); // Second function call

echo "<pre>";
print_r($hookparams);
echo "</pre>"
```